# Oddo Button returning Vendor Bills instead of Customer Invoice

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

When I click a button I had to goto Customer Invoice's Tree and Form View.Instead now it is going to Vendor Invoice.I tried like this in button click.

```
return {
               'name': "Invoice",
               'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
               'view_mode': 'tree,form',
                'xml_id': 'account.action_invoice_tree1',
                'tree_view_id': self.env.ref('account.invoice_tree').id,               
                'form_view_id': self.env.ref('account.invoice_form').id,               
               'target': 'current',
               'res_model':'account.invoice',
               'domain': [('id','in',[invoice_obj.id])],
           }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
'views': [(self.env.ref('account.invoice_tree').id, 'tree'),
          (self.env.ref('account.invoice_form').id, 'form')],
```

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and/or links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around them. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please edit your answer - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/22280057)